# facebook like button - iframe widget off page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fbml, xfbml, facebook-fbml

[image: facebook-box]

Hi, my facebook popin iframe widget from the like button is going off page.
is there a method to prevent this?

(the cut off portion on the right is the edge of my screen/browser)

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure your body tag has a fixed width to the actual width of the iframe (i.e. 520px)
- Or ensure the element you place the like button inside of is set to the correct width (so Facebook knows how to position its popup better)

Comment: private dev server, unable to post link.